# How do I create a table in SQLite using the VS2008 Server Explorer

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sqlite, server-explorer

I would like to create a table in a SQLite database using the Server Explorer in VS2008. I am able to do other operations on the database but when it comes to creating a table using the query builder I get  Not Supported messages. is there another way other than writing code just for the sole purpose of creating the table?

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR(100)
)
```

.NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite  3.6.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple front end for SQLite databases called [SqLiteMan](http://sqliteman.com/). You can create the database/tables very easily using this front end manager.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. I have no problems adding tables to an existing database using the Server Explorer tools.